# Why am I getting the error - Too many arguments from this formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, arguments

I am trying to create a macro for the following formula. First though, I need to get the formula working when referencing a spreadsheet saved separately on the hard drive. Below is what I have but I am getting the error of **Too many arguments**.

```
=IFERROR(IF(C2<>"",IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A2&"",[LPSMatch.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)="Assigned Attorney",OR(B2="Jimmy Edwards",B2="Kathleen McCarthy")),"Sales Team",IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A2&"",[LPSMatch.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)="Intake Team, Assigned Attorney, or Sales Team",B2<>"Jimmy Edwards",B2<>"Kathleen McCarthy"),B2,IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A2&"",[LPSMatch.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)="Intake Team, Assigned Attorney, or Sales Team",OR(B2="Jimmy Edwards",B2="Kathleen McCarthy")),"Sales Team",IF(VLOOKUP(A2&"",[LPSMatch.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)="Assigned Attorney",B2,IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A2&"",[LPSMatch.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)="Sales Team",OR(B2="Jimmy Edwards",B2="Kathleen McCarthy")),"Sales Team",IF(C2<>"",VLOOKUP(A2&"",[LPSMatch.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE),"INTAKE TEAM")))))), VLOOKUP(A2&"",[LPSMatch.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE),"")
```

Any help? When I go to the function help all of the arguments are okay but it highlights the "" at the end of my formula.

Comment: I suspect that the `VLOOKUP` calls are what are causing the problem.  Can you simplify the formula in some way?

Comment: If I can, I don't know how to.. :/

Comment: OK let's try pulling those `VLOOKUP` statements out and into their own cells.  Then reference those cells from your above formula.  Does the formula now work?

Comment: Also, one thing to note is that I used this same formula, and it worked, when I had the lookup table located in columns H and I... on the same sheet. Its only when I started referencing an external sheet that I got this error.

Comment: So, are you suggesting that, for example, the last vlookup, (, VLOOKUP(A2&"",[LPSMatch.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE),"")    that I instead reference a cell on the lpsmatch sheet, that has the same formula in it? Or, keep it on this spreadsheet?   (Basically, I need to keep this spreadsheet as clean as possible - which is why this formula is going to a macro after I get it working.. if I can)

Comment: I went ahead and pulled the last one out and put it into G2, leaving the below as the end of the formula - but, received the same error.                                                Team",IF(C2<>"",VLOOKUP(A2&"",[LPSMatch.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE),"INTAKE TEAM")))))),G2,"")

Comment: So I think you may need to do this will _all_ of the external `VLOOKUP` calls.

Comment: Actually, how is that going to work if the rows are changing? I can't reference A2 for everything... I am confused.

Comment: I don't think the problem per se is that your formula references another _sheet_, but rather that it referencing another _workbook_.  Can you import the external sheet you reference into the _same_ workbook where your current formula is?

Comment: I can, but the use of this lookup is to simplify a work daily process that has other lookup values added fairly regularly, so I need the lookup values to be located in a common drive so that when they are updated, this template is still usable.

Answer (score 1):

fwiw, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to add line feeds to your long formula and add a little legibility. The line feeds and 'white-space' do not negatively impact the formula's performance in any way.

[image: very long formula]

All I had to do to get it working in its current state was at a `)` to `... ,FALSE)), "")` at the tail end.

There is some repeated logic that could be paired up. Line 2 could be OR paired with line 6 and 9 and line 11 seems completely redundant as you are still following the TRUE path for the first `IF(C2<>"",...` and the 'nothing matches' default appears to be doubled up. Here is my best shot.

```
=IFERROR(IF(C2<>"",
         IF(AND(
                OR(VLOOKUP(A2&"",[LPSMatch.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B, 2, FALSE)={"Assigned Attorney","Sales Team","Intake Team, Assigned Attorney, or Sales Team"}),
                OR(B2={"Jimmy Edwards","Kathleen McCarthy"})), "Sales Team",
         IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A2&"",[LPSMatch.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)="Intake Team, Assigned Attorney, or Sales Team",
                OR(B2<>{"Jimmy Edwards","Kathleen McCarthy"})), B2,
         IF(VLOOKUP(A2&"",[LPSMatch.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)="Assigned Attorney", B2,
             VLOOKUP(A2&"",[LPSMatch.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)))), "INTAKE TEAM"), "")
```

An [OR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OR-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0) (or [AND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5F19B2E8-E1DF-4408-897A-CE285A19E9D9)) can compare to an array of constants; e.g. `=if(or("BCD" = {"abc", "bcd", "cde"}), ...` would be TRUE. Using this method reduces the [VLOOKUP functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) significantly.

Footnote: the formula you are using is for an external workbook that is open. You would need full path(s) to the workbook if it is closed. If you get the formula working, close the external workbook and all of the full path(s) will be added.